# Blue Ocean - How Do I Track Pull Requests AND the Master Branch

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-blueocean

I'm using Blue Ocean against Bitbucket Server.  I want a new build to occur:

- When a Pull Request is created or updated
- When master is updated (basically, when a PR is merged to master)

It appears that I can do the first by choosing "Discover Branches: Only branches that are also filed as PR's".  I can do the second by choosing "Filter by name: master".

But if I specify both, it seems to apply the name filter to discovered branches, so no PR's are ever discovered.  Furthermore, it never builds master because master is never the subject of a PR (we have master locked against direct commits, as is common in enterprise development.)

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out but it was not intuitive.  You must add two BitBucket Branch Sources, both pointing to the same Repository.  The first must be the Filter by Name: Master.  The second must be "Discover Branches: Only branches that are also filed as PR's".  If they're in the opposite order, they won't work.

Comment: Is this still working? I can't get it to work as you describe. I have the PR source working fine. I've tried adding sources for _Filter by Name (with wildcards)_ and for _File by Name (with regular expression)_, both before and after the PR source. I've tried adding the Filter sources in the same source as the PR source. Nothing is working :(

Comment: Got it working. My first source has two behaviours. The first is _Discover Branches_ with strategy _Exclude branches that are also filed as PRs_. The second behaviour of the first source is _Filter by name (with wildcards): *master*_. The second source is _Discover pull requests from origin_ with strategy _Merging the pull request with the current target branch revision". This is giving me the expected one branch _master_ and all pull requests (as visualized in Blue Ocean and Classic).